# Display <iframe> in random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In one of mine site I am displaying 3 different `<iframe>` into my site. Now as per my client requirement he wants to show any 1 `<iframe>` into the site in random oder.

Is there a way that we can do it.

Comment: Hi Pratik, At this point, your question is a bit broad. Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @kukic the example is very simple and I think I have also cleared the way out. I do not understand where do you think its too broad? Actually it is query for displaying 3 different html tag in random order. I agree  you might not have faced this issue. So you might feel it bit odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by following :-

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function randomdiv()
{
var elems = $("div");
if (elems.length) {
  var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    if (i !== keep) {
      $(elems[i]).hide();
    }
  }
}
}
</script>
```

And by adding following code on your Body tag

```
<div id="content1"><iframe src=""></iframe>  </div>
 <div id="content2"><iframe src=""></iframe> </div>
 <div id="content3"><iframe src=""></iframe> </div>
```